# (Python) How to check http response on status

Tags: python, http, response, status

can someone tell me how to check the statuscode of a HTTP response with http.client? I didn't find anything specifically to that in the documentary of http.client.
Code would look like this:

```
  if conn.getresponse():
    return True #Statuscode = 200
  else:
    return False #Statuscode != 200
```

My code looks like that:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import http.client, sys

def check_url(url):
  url = urlparse(url)
  conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url.netloc)
  conn.request("HEAD", url.path)
  r = conn.getresponse()
  if r.status == 200:
    return True
  else:
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
  input_url=input("Enter the website to be checked (beginning with www):")
  url = "http://"+input_url
  url_https = "https://"+input_url
  if check_url(url_https):
    print("The entered Website supports HTTPS.")
  else:
    if check_url(url):
      print("The entered Website doesn't support HTTPS, but supports HTTP.")
  if check_url(url):
    print("The entered Website supports HTTP too.")
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples), you simply needs to do:

```
r = conn.getresponse()
print(r.status, r.reason)
```

**Update**: If you want (as said in the comments) to check an http connection, you could eventually use an `HTTPConnection` and read the status:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("docs.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
```

If the website is correctly configured to implement HTTPS, you should not have a status code 200; In this example, you'll get a `301 Moved Permanently` response, which means the request was redirected, in this case rewritten to HTTPS .

Comment: Thank you that works, but my intention is to check if the website supports HTTPS and HTTP or only HTTP. But if i test a website which doesn't support HTTPS it still tells me it does support it. Do i check for the wrong statuscode when i check for "200"?

Comment: So for what statuscode i have to check when i want to equal test it? I mean i want to test the website if it works with HTTPS and if yes/no i want to check if it works with HTTP. But with my solution every website supports both, although some entered websites doesn't support HTTPS.
Thank you so far :)

Comment: Just send an HTTPSRequest, you should get an Exception (I think a `ConnectionRefusedError`) if the website does not support https...